# how to show many nested childs in a queryset in efficient way, for loops dont work

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

- I have created two models, 1st is Book and 2nd is SubBookPart (Sub Part of Book)
- User creates a  book first
- then add its sub part like "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2" and so on to that book
- then add "Page 1", "Page 2" and so on to each chapter
- then add "Paragraph 1", "Paragraph 2" and so on to each Para
- I successfully does this
- My Book Look Like This

```
BookName
|- Chapter 1
   |- Page 1
      |- Paragraph 1
      |- Paragraph 2
      |- Paragraph 3
   |- Page 2
      |- Paragraph 1
      |- Paragraph 2
      |- Paragraph 3

|- Chapter 2
   |- Page 1
      |- Paragraph 1
      |- Paragraph 2
      |- Paragraph 3
   |- Page 2
      |- Paragraph 1
      |- Paragraph 2
      |- Paragraph 3
   |- Page 3
      |- Paragraph 1
      |- Paragraph 2
      |- Paragraph 3
```

> But I dont know how to show it in frontend, because it will take very very long nested for loop, Is There and other way

`models.py`

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    subparts = models.ManyToManyField("SubBookPart", related_name="book_subparts", blank=True)

class SubBookPart(models.Model):
    # for only first sub part
    subpart_of_book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)

    # for only non-first sub parts, giving reference to previous subpart
    subpart_of = models.ForeignKey("SubBookPart", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    # subpart name like chapter, page, paragraph, line and so on
    subpart_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    # title like chaptername, para 2, page 4, line 5 etc
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    # if this subpart contains more sub parts, this is used when book has many sub divisions
    subparts = models.ManyToManyField("SubBookPart", related_name="sub_subparts", blank=True)
```

`bookview.html`

```
{{book.name}}

<ul>
    {% for part in book.subparts.all %}
    <li>{{part}}</li>
    <ul>
        {% for firstpart in part.subparts.all %}
        <li>{{firstpart}}</li>
        <ul>
            {% for secondpart in firstpart.subparts.all %}
            <li>{{secondpart}}</li>
            <ul>
                {% for thirdpart in secondpart.subparts.all %}
                <li>{{thirdpart}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: You can prefetch the related objects to reduce the queries, so: `Book.objects.prefetch_related("subparts__subparts__subparts__subparts")`, which should do just 5 queries instead of n^4